# Angularjs CORS trouble with Node, Express, Oauth2, and Passport

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, oauth, cors

Recently we have decided to switch our front-end from EJS to Angular separate the frontend and the backend completely.  In doing so, we started to run into several issues across multiple browsers.  On the back end we are using Node with express along with passport and oauth2.  For the front end we are attempting to use angular.  EJS works using express.render, but we would prefer to use angular directly by utilizing express as just a RESTful API.

I'm running both the backend and frontend locally at localhost:8080 and localhost:3000, respectfully.  When just working with the backend (USING EJS, NOT ANGULAR), I can successfully go to our backend port in the browser, login via passport-oauth, and be redirect to the account page (from the providers login screen) where my json data is rendered via res.json. The problem is I am unable to do this from the frontend UI after removing EJS.

I've tried configuring CORS a dozen different ways while using three different browsers with no luck.  The following three snippets are the errors I'm getting in the browsers console while trying to access localhost:8080 from the frontend via $http and $resource (see below for the code).  The image below the three code snippets is what the node console is telling me when trying to access port 8080 from each different browser...

**Chrome:**

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load 'PROVIDER-DETAILS-URL'. No 'Access-Control-Allow-    Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore     not allowed access.
```

**Firefox:**

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at 'PROVIDER-DETAILS-URL'. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at 'PROVIDER-DETAILS-URL'. (Reason: CORS request failed).
```

**Safari:**

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/auth/PROVIDER. Request header field Accept-Encoding is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.
```

**Console Image:**
[image]

**And the code:**

### Server:

**app.js**

```
'use strict';

const express           = require('express');
const session           = require('express-session');
const cookieParser      = require('cookie-parser');
const bodyParser        = require('body-parser');
const logger            = require('morgan');
const errorHandler      = require('errorhandler');
const path              = require('path');
const flash             = require('connect-flash');
const passport          = require('passport');
const expressValidator  = require('express-validator');

/**
 * Load environment variables, where API keys and passwords are configured.
 */
const config = require('./config/config');

/**
 * Route Handlers
 */
const index   = require('./routes/index');
const account = require('./routes/account');
const logout  = require('./routes/logout');

/**
 * API keys and Passport configuration.
 */
const passportConfig = require('./strategy');

/**
 * Create Express server.
 */
const app = express();

/**
 * Express configuration.
 */
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, HEAD, POST, PUT");
    next();
});
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(expressValidator());
app.use(session({
    resave              : true,
    saveUninitialized   : true,
    secret              : config.sessionSecret,
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(flash());

/**
 * Primary app routes.
 */
app.get('/', index.execute);
app.get('/account', passportConfig.isAuthenticated, account);
app.get('/logout', logout.execute);

/**
 * OAuth authorization routes.
 */
app.get('/auth/PROVIDER', passport.authenticate('PROVIDER'));
app.get('/auth/PROVIDER/callback', passport.authenticate('PROVIDER', { failureRedirect : '/'}), function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/account');
});

/**
 * Error Handler.
 */
app.use(errorHandler());

/**
 * Start Express server.
 */
app.listen(8080, () => {
    console.log('App listening on port 8080');
});

module.exports = app;
```

**strategy.js**

```
'use strict';

const passport        = require('passport');
const session         = require('express-session');
const config          = require('./config/config');
const OAuth2Strategy  = require('passport-oauth').OAuth2Strategy;

/**
 * Put together the right header info for PROVIDER
 */
 var authString      = new Buffer(config.PROVIDER.clientID + ':' + config.PROVIDER.clientSecret);
 var customHeader    = {
    "Authorization": "Basic " + authString.toString('base64')
};

/**
 * OAuth2Strategy containing the customHeader created above.
 */
 passport.use('PROVIDER', new OAuth2Strategy({
    authorizationURL    : config.PROVIDER.authorizationURL,
    tokenURL            : config.PROVIDER.tokenURL,
    clientID            : config.PROVIDER.clientID,
    clientSecret        : config.PROVIDER.clientSecret,
    callbackURL         : config.PROVIDER.callbackURL,
    customHeaders       : customHeader,
    passReqToCallback   : true
},
function( req, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done ) {
    req.session.accessToken = accessToken;
    return done(null, profile); 
}
));

 passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    return done(null, user);
});

 passport.deserializeUser(function(obj, done) {
    return done(null, obj);
});

/**
 * Login Required middleware.
 */
 exports.isAuthenticated = function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        console.log('isAuthenticated');
        return next();
    }
    res.redirect('/');
};

/**
 * Authorization Required middleware.
 */
 exports.isAuthorized = function(req, res, next) {
    var provider = req.path.split('/').slice(-1)[0];
    if (_.find(req.user.tokens, { kind: provider })) {
        next();
    } else {
        res.redirect('/auth/' + provider);
    }
};
```

**index.js**

```
exports.execute = function (req, res) {
    if (req.user) {
        console.log('========== ROUTES/INDEX.JS | 3 ==========');
        res.redirect('/account');
    } else {
        console.log('========== ROUTES/INDEX.JS | 6 ==========');
        res.redirect('/auth/PROVIDER');
    }
};
```

### Client:

I combined this to make it a little easier to read.

```
angular.module('StackOverflowPost', [])

.factory('APIService', function() {
    function getData( $q, $http ) {
        var defer = $q.defer();
        $http.get( 'localhost:8080' )
            .success( getDataComplete )
            .catch( getDataFailed );

        function getDataComplete( response ) {
            console.log( response.Authorization );
            defer.resolve(response.data.results );
        }

        function getDataFailed( error ) {
            console.log( error.data );
            defer.reject( 'XHR Failed for getData - ' + error.data );
        }
        return defer.promise;
    }
})

.controller('MainCtrl', function( APIService ) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.getDataTest = function() {
        APIService.getData().then(function( returnedData ) {
            console.log( returnedData );
        })
    }
});
```

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE** *(4/28/2016)*: I updated the original post with more details. I also updated the code to what it is after another week of trial and error.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this

https://gist.github.com/dirkk0/5967221

Code should be

```
// in AngularJS (client)

myApp.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {

    $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
    delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
}]);

// in Express/nodeJS

// in NodeJS/Express (server)
app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST","PUT");
   next();

});
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still getting the same errors in the console for all three browsers, but I appreciate the attempt.

Comment: @Matt Did you got any solution?